# HUGE PROBLEM! Can't log in to Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrade to 15.10, stuck at login screen

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.10, login-screen, do-release-upgrade

So I started the upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 15.10. Everything was going okay until it logged out. Even the guest session is not working tried upgrading from terminal with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd> but it says:

`

> E: Unmet Dependicies. Try using -f

`
and when I try to update or reinstall unity the terminal says 
'

> W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max

'

Answer (score 2):

Reboot. Try to boot into the recovery system from grub. When it comes up, or anything with a CLI, do (as root) a `apt-get -f install`. Let the update process finish, you can make sure with `apt update && apt full-upgrade` that no error messages remain.

Your system should be in a usable state then, this happens more often than I like.

Comment: how can I boot into the rescue system from grub??

Comment: It should be the second entry in the menu, directly below the highlighted Ubuntu entry at grub start. Ubuntu recovery, not grub rescue.

Details are at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode, you press shift during boot to get to the grub menu if you have only Ubuntu on this machine.